# What is more natural: 'people like you' or 'person as you'?

Tags: word-choice, as-like

> It's nice to have people **like** you here.
>
> It's nice to have people **as** you here.
>
> It's nice to have persons **like** you here.
>
> It's nice to have persons **as** you here.

I always say there is nobody like me except me.

Which says it better, or is there better wording than these options?

Answer (score 1):

- I’m sure that you, just like the rest of us, are unique
  (“I’m not!”, yells a voice in the back), but “like” means “similar to”, not “identical to”,
  so (unless you’re really weird) there are probably people “like you”.
- I’m sure somebody will come along and point out a glaring counterexample to this,
  but, off the cuff, I’d say that “people” and “persons” are close enough in meaning
  that they are nearly interchangeable in contexts like this. 
  (I believe that “people” sounds better, but I offer that only as my personal opinion.)
- I vote for “It’s nice to have people like you here.”
  as the best option that’s currently listed on the page,
  but an alternative structure is “Having people like you here is nice.”

Answer (score 1):

No.1 and no. 3: right (no. 1 better). No. 2 and no. 4: wrong.
Put "people like you" and "people as you" in Google and (forget the numbers, useless in this case) look at the short descriptions in the first pages.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine anyone saying "persons like you" though I'm not sure why it sounds so bad.

"the person or persons like you are here" is the closest I can come.

Answer (score 0):

This question opens up Pandora's box.  That said, this is my opinion on your examples.

In formal writing, we would say "It is nice to have people such as you here."

In informal speech, we would say "It's nice to have people like you here," and would slightly emphasize "you."  If they didn't want the comparison aspect they would emphasize "like."

The reason I say Pandora's box is because a lot of people are going to object and say "I never do that."

I would not use "persons" because this is reserved for legal matters or when talking about occupancy in an elevator or public space.  I don't know anyone who talks about individuals as a group and uses persons rather than "people."  It also seems that English speakers use person when speaking of an individual and people when talking about more than one, or groups.

We use "like" to say something is similar and "as" when something is exactly the same.  "Like" is usually used for people.  "Like" is usually followed by a noun or gerund, "as" is followed by a subject and verb.  If we want to use "as" we will say "such as."  This is why number two is not correct.

Number three is grammatically correct but only for certain legal uses.  I can't think of one but then I'm not an attorney...perhaps someone with a legal background can add to this.

In short, I would tell my students "use example one and you'll be fine."

Answer (score -2):

"Like" is a preposition, and takes an object. "As" is a conjunction, and joins to clauses, even if one of them is mostly elided as parallelism.

So statements 1 and 2 are both correct:

1. It's nice to have persons like you here.
2. It's nice to have people who act as you do.

"It's nice to have people who act like you" is a grammatical sentence, but it means something else. It's referring to people who are imitating you.

"It's nice to have people who act like you do" is ungrammatical, though quite common.

Comment: *Like* has been used as a conjunction since the early sixteenth century.  I'm not sure of what makes it ungrammatical.

Comment: *"It's nice to have people who act like you do" is ungrammatical* Absolute nonsense. It's completely grammatical.

Comment: _Like_ and _as_ are **both** prepositions in this context (and conjunctions in others). As @curiousdannii says, there is nothing ungrammatical about “people who act like [_or_ as] you do”. “People as you” (as in statements 2 and 4), on the other hand, is quite jarring to me—if not flat out ungrammatical, then at least bordering on it. “Persons as you” is certainly ungrammatical to me. “People who act like you” does not necessarily mean people who imitate you. In short, there is very little about this answer that is not just plain **wrong**.